# [iOS][Objective-C] Expected type

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, point

I have a Problem in one of my Objective-C classes.

Xcode said that there is a Parse Issue in line 20.

```
+ (Boolean)hasOverlay:(KnownPoints*)points byPoint:(CGPoint)p;
```

KnownPoints is a self written Class. Xcode displays that the error is at the part '(KnownPoints*)points.

The answer of an other similar topic to add this Codeline:

```
@class KnownPoints
```

does not work.

The class is called in a calculation class which makes latitudes and longitudes to x and y coordiantes form a view.

Here the Code: (CalcMakerPos.h)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "Journey.h"
#import "CoordRect.h"
#import "KnownPoints.h"


@interface CalcMakerPos : NSObject


+ (CGPoint)calcPosFor: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord WithDataFrom: (CoordRect*)rect     AtView: (UIView*)view;
+ (Boolean)hasOverlay:(KnownPoints*)points byPoint:(CGPoint)p;
@end
```

CalcMakerPos.m

```
#import "CalcMakerPos.h"
#import "MinMaxCoords.h"
#import "Journey.h"
#import "KnownPoints.h"

@implementation CalcMakerPos
#pragma mark Calculate GeoCoords zu Pixeln
+ (CGPoint)calcPosFor: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord WithDataFrom: (CoordRect*)rect AtView: (UIView*)view{

     double maxLat = [rect maxLat];
     double minLat = [rect minLat];
     double maxLon = [rect maxLon];
     double minLon = [rect minLon];
     int x = (int)((coord.longitude - minLon) / (maxLon - minLon) * view.frame.size.width);
     int y = (int)((coord.latitude - minLat) / (maxLat - minLat) * view.frame.size.height);
     NSLog(@"Point(%d, %d)", x,y);
     return CGPointMake(x, y);
}

#pragma mark check whether point is free
+ (Boolean)hasOverlay:(KnownPoints*)points byPoint:(CGPoint)p{
    BOOL isOverLay = false;

    return isOverLay;
}
@end
```

I hope you can help me.

Greetings form Germany

Robybyte

Comment: Not sure about the actual problem, but you have duplicate imports of "Journey.h" and "KnownPoints.h". Remove them from "CalcMakerPos.m".

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by circular import statements.

Make sure that `CalcMakerPos` is not imported or added as `@class` into `KnownPoints`.

Comment: I have tidied up the import statemenets - and it will work now.

Answer (score 0):

`KnownPoints` and `Journey` are being imported twice. Remove the imports from the implementation file because they are redundant.

Clean and build your project after that.